# iPhone : How to create .mht file for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

Is it possible to make .mht (web Archive) file for iPhone ?

.mht(web Archive) where the image is embedded into html file. So it can be easy way to send `html` in email which contain images.

So How do I make this type of file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's [Safari browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML#Safari), which runs on the iPhone, does *not* support the .mht file extension.

You may try using the [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data%3a_URI_scheme) instead, which is more portable.

Answer (score 0):

if what you want to do is only to embed images into your HTML formatted emails, try base64 encoding for your images. all the taste without the pain :)